# MySQL account has password, but only logs in without it

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 trying to host a Drupal site. Because it is Drupal, I am trying to connect to a MySQL server rather than a MSSQL server. I created a new schema as well as a new user and I gave the new user a password. When I try to setup Drupal and connect to the server with a password, I get this response:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'multi_beta'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

When I try connecting without a password I get this response:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'multisite_beta'.
```

What is bizarre is that even though I set a password for the account, when I log on using those credential via command line, if I don't use a password it works, while if I do use a password it doesn't. I know I'm using the correct password.

This is the second time this has happened to me and the only solution the first time was to wait it out. I tried changing the password, using different user names, trying difference schemas, using dashes instead of underscores, specifying the port, restarting the server, but nothing has solved it. Is there something wrong with my server configuration? Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: How did you create the account, if using manual DDL, did you flush privileges?  What do you get for `show grants for 'multi_beta'@'%';`

Comment: `'GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO \'multi_beta\'@\'%\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'------------------------------------\''
'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, TRIGGER ON `multisite\\_beta`.* TO \'multi_beta\'@\'%\''`

Comment: I created the account and the schema using the MySQL Workbench GUI.

Comment: How are you trying to connect to test?  Are you using the CLI?  Try setting the hostname too.  So a command like `mysql -h server.fqdn -u multi_beta -p`.  BTW, it would be better to edit the results into your question, then try to include formatted multi-line results in a comment.

Comment: I've tried connecting with the CLI and with the Drupal installation. Even when setting the hostname, the same error occurs. Without a password its successful, but with a password it isn't. My goal is for login to be the opposite of that,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, when I changed the password in using MySQL Workbench, the changes wouldn't propagate throughout the server. I needed to change the password via the command line, then it worked.